# Return jsons with references as one single object?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following json documents setup in the same collection in an azure cosmos db:

```
videoData:
{
   id: string,
   url: string,
   previewImage: string
}

videoDisplay
{
   id: string,
   width: number,
   height: number,
   videoDataId: string // points to id in videoData.id
}
```

I'd like to do an sql query in azure  which will resolve to an array looking something like:

```
[
{
   id: string //videoDisplay
   width: number,
   height: number,
   videoData: videoData // videoDataId resolved to videoData which is now stored in video data
}
]
```

Is this doable? More importantly would this be an appropriate solution to the problem i'm trying to resolve (tying up video display foreign key with video data).

Comment: Please have a try, any concern please free feel to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, I suggest using stored procedure to merge your documents.Please refer to my working steps:

***sample documents:***

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "url": "ad",
        "previewImage": "sda"
    },
    {
        "id": "string",
        "width": "number",
        "height": "number",
        "videoDataId": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "string2",
        "width": "number",
        "height": "number",
        "videoDataId": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "url": "ad",
        "previewImage": "sda"
    }
]
```

***Stored Procedure code:***

```
function sample() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var map ={};  
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT c.id,c.url,c.previewImage FROM c where NOT is_defined(c.videoDataId)',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            for(var i=0 ; i <feed.length;i++){
               map[feed[i].id] = feed[i];
            }
        }
    });

    var a = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT c.id,c.width,c.height,c.videoDataId,{} as videoData FROM c where is_defined(c.videoDataId)',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            for(var i=0 ; i <feed.length;i++){
               feed[i].videoData = map[feed[i].videoDataId];
            }
            var response = getContext().getResponse();          
            response.setBody(feed);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

Hope it helps you.